# How do I make Cycles bake only to the texture which I specify?

Tags: texture-baking

Every time I use the bake function, it bakes to the texture that I've selected, but also completely erases some of my other image files. This is extremely annoying because I have to re-open each of my images. How do I stop it from doing that?

Comment: To "stop it" from doing that you will need to deselect any other Image Texture node in all materials avialable for the object and make sure there is Image Texture node with image to bake to in those materials. Cycles bakes to currently selected image.

Answer (score 1):

Create an image and put it into node editor, without connecting it to other nodes.